# How do I write a query which based on hierarchies?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table `t1` with:

```
ID  CODE  
1   A  
1   B  
1   C  
2   C  
2   D
```

And another table `t2` that provides me the hierarchies. (so what inferior really means is that if code A, B and C all exist for a specific `ID`, we should really only use code A. and if code C and D both exist, we should really only use code C)

```
CODE  INFERIOR  
A      B  
A      C  
C      D
```

How do I write the query in plsql that give me the following results?

```
ID  CODE  
1   A   
2   C
```

Comment: Meaning the topmost elements for each ID? Isn't that just where-not-exists a row in the second table where the code is in the 'inferior' column?

Comment: @Rup looks like it. You should post it as an answer so that OP can close.

Comment: @Julien Actually re-reading the question I think it's about de-duplication; if we had "3 B" in the top table and no other 3s we should probably return that too.

Comment: Rather than topmost elements (which would exclude C), it appears to be asking for all parent elements. However, it is not clear why ID 2 is supposed to be returned for code C by the query - both IDs 1 and 2 are recorded for code C.

Comment: @Rup Yes. If say, a specific ID only has B (not A and C), then the results should return the B. If a specific ID has both A and C, it meets one of the conditions in table 2, then it should really only return A. However, if all A,B,C exist for an ID, then only return A... Hope that make sense. Thanks!

Comment: OP's structure is simply 2 tree. In tree #1, you have `ParentA-ChildB`, and `ParentA-ChildC`, making A a topmost node. In tree #2, you have `ParentC-ChildD` making C a topmost node.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard - that's correct... not sure how to write this query.

Answer (score 2):

Current query is for SQL-Server 2008, if there's any issue just tell me where your problem is and what your DBMS is and I'll try to adapt the code.

```
SELECT a.id, a.code 
FROM t1 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 b ON b.inferior = a.code
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 c ON c.code = b.code and c.id=a.id
where c.code is null;
```

The idea is basically to try and match each entry of `t1` with another entry that has the same `id` and shares a child-parent relationship. Once that's done, you simply need to find those who don't have a parent.

Comment: I can confirm this works on Oracle, which is the OP's RDBMS (as per the request for PL/SQL)

Comment: Thank you!! Will try this in a bit. Thank you all!

Comment: That doesn't do multi-level relationships, though, where the middle level is missing (but I don't know if that's a requirement) e.g. if we had 3A, 3D should the output just be 3A because  A>C>D?

Comment: @Rup a week later, I happened to understand your comment. It will actually return A and D if you don't have the C node since that tree would have 2 top-most nodes It's possible to alter the query to return only A based on needs.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard Finally get to test this. Actually I would want to just return A. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: In that case, it's quite a bit harder and you will likely need to concatenate your t2, and at that point, the answer will vary wildly between Oracle 11g and previous versions.